# Relative Gantt in MS project?

Tags: charts, microsoft-project

Is there a way to create a relative Gantt in MS project, that is a Gantt that doesn't have a defined start date, just amount of time required for each task?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you didn't want to show specific dates, a generic 'duration' schedule?  This is referred to as an Ordinal timescale in Primavera's schedule software.  MS Project achieves this by change the timescale labels to show 'month 1', 'month 2', etc. -- then just hide any date columns and you have a generic schedule.

Comment: Is it possible to not have the month X as well?

Just the duration is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

from http://www.gantt-chart.biz/display-relative-week-numbers-in-ms-project/
Check on comment at the end

> MS Project help is lame. I am using MSP 2010, formula that actually worked was
>   CStr(1+DateDiff(”w”,[Project Start],[Start]))
>   Notice that it uses comma (”,”) instead of semicolon (”;”). I also added
>   & “w”
>   to the end for display of units (weeks, in this case)
>   Odd enough, when you paste it the first time, it’ll point at error on “w” token. Then you just erase the token and TYPE it back, and voila!!

Answer (score 0):

You can do that only if your project structure does not use hard constraints (MSO, MFO...). This will allow you to just change the project start date and all the project to be rescheduled relative to that date.

Comment: The idea is just to see the duration - without actual start date. This Gantt goes to marketing, so it quite uncomfortable to update it every time.